# User Profile service is showing 35 UserProfile while the UserProfileSyncService is stopped and we did not define any Sync Connections

Tags: 2013, user-profile, user-profile-service, active-directory, administration

I have started working on a new sharepoint farm 2013 on-premises for our customer, and first thing i checked is the managed services they have which seems fine, except for the User Profile Service, which is showing 35 user profiles, although the User Profile Sync Service is stopped and they do not have any Sync Connections!!, as follow:-

1. when i access the User Profile managed service, i found that currently there are 35 user profile:-

[image]

2. so i wanted to know how they are syncing the user profiles, so first thing i found is that the User Profile Sync service is stopped as follow:-

[image]

3. also from Manage Service application >> User Profile Service >> Sync Connections, it does not contain any entry, as follow:-

[image]

4. finally here is the sync settings they have, which depend on the User Profile Sync service:-

[image]

So i got confused on how the 35 user profiles are there, although the UserProfileSyncService is stopped + they did not define any Sync Connections + the sync setting is set to use the stopped User Profile Sync service ?? so how things are being handled ?

Thanks

**Edit**
Now when i click on a username inside one site collection, i got this page `http://servername/sites/siteA/_layouts/15/userdisp.aspx?ID=12`:-

[image]

while on another site collection i will get this page `http://servername/sites/siteB/_layouts/15/userdisp.aspx?ID=1`, where less properties and also different properties are being shown (for example here the email is shown inside a property named e-mail, where on the first page the property is named as work email):-

[image]

but inside the User Profile service, there is only one user defined not 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user visit a site collection, it's profile with basic information created by default in UP A. At this time it does not matter whether a sync connection established or not.

Now, if you configure the sync connection...then it will import all user from the source (ad or any other) based on your criteria which u define in connection and filters.

If you don't have profile sync then users,s profile with basic information will be in upa but never update from AD. But if you have sync service then all the properties will be synced properly according when sync job ran.

Comment: thanks for your useful information, so now i can say that only 35 users have actually access any site inside our sharepoint farm?? i mean since there is no sync and there are 35 user profiles created , so i can conclude that only 35 users have actually  visited the sites? i am asking this to understand if i understand your comment properly?

Comment: second point Why when i click on a username inside 2 different site collections i will get different info inside the `/_layouts/15/userdisp.aspx?ID=**` page? and also the same user will have different id on different site collection? but at the end i will have only one user profile for this user inside the User Profile Service? can u adivce on these 2 points please?

Comment: Yes that's true...only 35 users access it...secondly because sync is not enabled that's why information us not properly synced....btw what the difference u are seeing?

Comment: thanks for ur reply. can u please check my edit inside my original question ?